# Exception occurring just in PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I get `'NoneType' object is not callable'` when I try to **debug** the following code in PyCharm IDE.
I don't get the same error when debbuging at Visual Studio Code nor when I run the code without debugging in Pycharm.

```py
new_dataframe = dataframe.replace("\"", "", regex = True)
```

This code snippet also replicates the error:

```py
import pandas

dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()
dataframe['PMES'] = ['No', None]

new_dataframe = dataframe.replace("\"", "", regex = True)

teste = ""
```

This is my DataFrame (saw in DataViewer) in Visual Studio Code

[DataFrame in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Ran.png)

This is the DataFrame in PyCharm.

[DataFrame in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAoEe.png)

Both DataFrames where visualized in the same project, with the same code, the error occurs only in PyCharm.

**UPDATE**

Here's the full PyCharm traceback with censhorship.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\???\???\???\???\???\???\???\conversion\tabula\__init__.py", line 133, in format_dataframe
    new_dataframe = dataframe.replace("\"", "", regex = True)
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5238, in replace
    return super().replace(
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6609, in replace
    new_data = self._mgr.replace(
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 437, in replace
    return self.apply(
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 327, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 686, in replace
    return self._replace_regex(to_replace, value, inplace=inplace)
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 759, in _replace_regex
    replace_regex(new_values, rx, value, mask)
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\array_algos\replace.py", line 152, in replace_regex
    f = np.vectorize(re_replacer, otypes=[np.object_])
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2120, in __init__
    otypes = ''.join([_nx.dtype(x).char for x in otypes])
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2120, in <listcomp>
    otypes = ''.join([_nx.dtype(x).char for x in otypes])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: I suspect that the code triggering the error about `NoneType` not being callable is not in the line of code that you showed. It's best to copy-and-paste into your question the *full* traceback with line numbers, not just the last error message.

Comment: why don't you use the single quote to get a string with double quote `'"'`

Comment: @jjramsey did it, there's an update with the traceback

Comment: @rioV8 because i settled as pattern in my project double quotes, i dont wanna change it in this situation since i can escape it

Comment: Your traceback doesn't contain your original `'NoneType' object is not callable` error message.

Comment: @jjramsey i'm so sorry, i just updated it with the correct traceback

Comment: i also added a small code to replicate the error

Comment: Looks like you ran into a problem with the module `debugpy` described here: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/801

Comment: @jjramsey very clarifying, thank you so much! if possible post ur answer to be voted as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [known numpy bug #21008](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21008) with Python 3.10. There are plenty of complaints about this on the [PyCharm boards](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52137) too. The internal numpy discussion suggests that a fix is expected with [numpy 1.22.4](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/milestone/105). Until then, Python 3.9.12 seems to be free of this problem.